# How to fetch the value and type of each column of each row in a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How can I convert a dataframe to a tuple that includes the datatype for each column?

I have a number of dataframes with varying sizes and types.  I need to be able to determine the type and value of each column and row of a given dataframe so I can perform some actions that are type-dependent.

So for example say I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
+-------+-------+
|  foo  |  bar  |
+-------+-------+
| 12345 | fnord |
|    42 |   baz |
+-------+-------+
```

I need to get

```
Seq(
  (("12345", "Integer"), ("fnord", "String")),
  (("42", "Integer"), ("baz", "String"))
)
```

or something similarly simple to iterate over and work with programmatically.

Thanks in advance and sorry for what is, I'm sure, a very noobish question.

Comment: It occurs to me that a much simpler way to phrase this question might be "how can I convert a dataframe to a 2d array that includes datatypes for each column?"

Comment: Have you looked at the `schema` method?  Also, you probably don't want or need to construct a new tuple for every column of every row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, then following shall be your solution.

```
  val df = Seq(
    (12345, "fnord"),
    (42, "baz"))
    .toDF("foo", "bar")
```

This creates dataframe which you already have.

```
+-----+-----+
|  foo|  bar|
+-----+-----+
|12345|fnord|
|   42|  baz|
+-----+-----+
```

Next step is to extract `dataType` from the `schema` of the `dataFrame` and create a `iterator`.

```
val fieldTypesList = df.schema.map(struct => struct.dataType)
```

Next step is to convert the `dataframe` `rows` into `rdd` list and `map` each `value` to `dataType` from the `list` created above

```
  val dfList = df.rdd.map(row => row.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",").toList)
  val tuples = dfList.map(list => list.map(value => (value, fieldTypesList(list.indexOf(value)))))
```

Now if we print it

```
tuples.foreach(println)
```

It would give

```
List((12345,IntegerType), (fnord,StringType))
List((42,IntegerType), (baz,StringType))
```

Which you can iterate over and work with programmatically